# Функция умножения матриц комплексных чисел 4096 х 4096

Tags: c++

Задали лабу. Т.к. в плюсах не силен, решил использовать вектора.

```
vector<vector<complex<double>>>firstMethod(vector<vector<complex<double>>> A,vector<vector<complex<double>>> B)
{
    vector< vector <complex <double>> > Arr(size_, vector<complex<double>>(size_));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < size_; j++)
        {
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < size_; k++)
            {
                Arr[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return Arr;
}
```

Где вектор A - первая матрица комплексных double чисел, вектор B - вторая соответственно.
Есть ли способ нормального перемножения двух таких матриц 4096*4096, или матрицы с 17млн комплексных дабл чисел невозможно умножить быстро? (п1. По формуле из линейной алгебры).
size_ = 4096;

Comment: Это не совсем оптимизация, но не передавайте в функцию вектора по значению - зачем их копировать? Лучше передать как константные ссылки. Сам алгоритм ускорить - ну, можно распараллелить вычисления, можно применить алгоритм типа Штрассена, но это будет достаточно сложная работа - его реализация...

Comment: Благодарю, но можно ли как-то существенней ускорить работу данной функции? Ведь я не представляю, как можно сделать быстрые вычисления таких огромный матриц! Ведь только заполнение 2-ух матриц случайными комплексными числами занимает +-20 секунд.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, а использование других контейнеров может улучшить ситуацию?

Comment: если одну матрицу предварительно транспонировать и получить прирост за счет того, что данные будут лучше в кеш ложится. Если же станет работать медленнее, значит транспонировали не ту матрицу. А потом можно применить ещё sse операции и получит 2.5-3 раза прирост. А потом узнать о алгоритме https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0 и ещё ускориться

Comment: В задании есть 3 метода умножения матриц, 1 из линейной алгебры, 2 из библиотеки BLAS, 3 свой, можно там Штрассена и реализовать. Спасибо.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86&lr=213&src=suggest_T